# How to unset a field for all objects of a nested array in lodash

Tags: lodash

I have an object like that:

```
var o = { a: [{b:'c'},{b:'d'}]}
```

I want to delete the b property of all objects of the array. I tried using
something like `_.unset(a, 'a.b')` or `_.unset(a, 'a[].b')` but doesn't work. Is there a magic expression that unset supports which could do this thing?

Comment: `unset` doesn't support this. (See https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L4320.)

Comment: Do you want to get `{ a: [{},{}]}` for `{ a: [{b:'c'},{b:'d'}]}`?

Comment: @MikhailShabrikov Right

Comment: @smarx Thx for lightning fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `unset` alone will do it, but it shouldn't be hard to accomplish.

```js
var o = { a: [{a:'fish', b:'test', c:'styx'},{b:'c'},{b:'d'}]};
_.forEach(o.a, (obj) => {_.unset(obj, 'b')});

console.log(o);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```